# Joinning two regular expressions together

Tags: python, regex

I have two regular expressions, one matching for all characters `[a-z]` and the other excluding the following combination of characters `[^spuz(ih)]` (the characters `s, p, u, z, ih`)how would I combine these two so that I could allow all alphanumeric characters except those listed in the second RE?

```
(re.match(r'^[a-z]*(?![spuz]|ih)[a-z]s$', insert_phrase)
```

Comment: Your this regex - `[^spuz(ih)]` does not matches what you think it matches. You cannot have captured group in character class. So, it excludes: - `s, p, u, z, (, i, h, )`

Comment: Ok in that case are there any ways where I can exclude captured groups?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here. This matches things containing only letters, where the one but last letter is not s, p, u, or z, and the last letter is s. The check for ih is not relevant, because if that would match, the last letter isn't s anyway (because it would be h). Do you want the string to end on s, not preceded by s, p, u, z, or ih? In that case negative lookbehind would be a solution.

Comment: I would like my string to end on s, and not be followed by s, p, u, z or 'ih' and have 0 or more characters preceding it before it hits the last but one letter.

Comment: How about providing examples of what you want to match and not match?

Comment: @KOM: You say "I would like my string to end on s" but then "and not be followed by". If it _ends_ on s, then it _won't_ be followed by anything. Definitely need some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "combine" them as such, but you can write another regular expression which has the same effect. For this, you can use the (?!) construct. It matches 0 characters only if the regular expression in it is *not* matched by the following part. So you can use:

```
'(?![spuz(ih)])[a-z]'
```

Or, since this wasn't what you wanted, change it to:

```
'(?![spuz]|ih)[a-z]'
```

In the changed question, you seem to want negative lookbehind instead. This turns the pattern into:

```
'^[a-z]*(?<![a-z][spuz]|ih)s$'
```

Note the extra [a-z] in the lookbehind part. It is required because lookbehind expressions must be fixed width. This means that a string like 'ps' *will* match the pattern, but you don't want that. So instead, it's better to use two separate lookbehinds (both of which have to be be true for the string to match):

```
'^[a-z]*(?<![spuz])(?<!ih)s$'
```

Comment: As an addendum, a pattern that uses (?!YourPatternHere) is called negative lookahead.  It's a non-consuming match in your pattern.  You can also do positive lookahead patterns, which also do not consume characters, but will make sure that the matched characters are there for the expression to return true.

Comment: Ok after some testing it appears my code based on the above isn't working, still appears to not ignore grouped characters, I will add my code above